# How do I pop() from a list without using pop()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function called pop_item() that I am trying to make act like a pop() that works with the list class, how would I do that, here is my code:
    def empty(lst):
        return lst == []

```
def pop_item(lst):
    lst = lst[::-1]
    new_lst = []
    for i in lst:
        if i != lst[-1]:
            new_lst += [i]
    lst = new_lst
    return lst

def main():
    todo = [1,2,3,4]

    print(todo) #prints [1,2,3,4] as expected


    print('\n' + 75 * '_' + '\n')

    print(pop_item(todo)) #pop the item off
    print(todo) #output should then be [1,2,3]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note: I am not allowed to use any built in functions eg len(),index,del() etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  "Here is my code" is not a problem specification.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Comment: try `[x for x in todo if x!=todo[-1]]`

Comment: what about try [x for x in todo if x == todo[-1]]? @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: are you allowed to use slice?

Comment: yes @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 1):

Dramatically more efficient than listcomps and broad slicing is using a single-item slice assignment:

```
def pop_item(lst, index=-1):  # index is -1 by default so it pops from the end
    obj = lst[index]          # Save off the object being popped to return it
    lst[index:index+1 or None] = ()  # Remove it from the list
    return obj                # Return the saved off object to the caller
```

`lst[index:index+1 or None] = ()` is equivalent to `del lst[index]`, aside from never throwing exceptions; thankfully, the indexing operation on the prior line will throw the exception for us.

The `del` version is essentially how `list.pop` is implemented, and it's amortized `O(1)` work (when `index` is the default `-1`) and a single `O(n)` operation when it's popping from elsewhere in the `list` (as opposed to slicing and listcomps, which involve multiple `O(n)` shallow copy operations, no matter where you pop from).

Your original code differed from `list.pop` in that:

1. It deleted based on value, not index
2. It could delete multiple items, not just one
3. It reversed the input for no apparent reason
4. It left the input unchanged rather than removing an item from the caller's `list`
5. It returned a mutated copy of the input `list`, rather than the popped item

The replacement has none of these issues, and behaves essentially identically to `list.pop`.

Comment: @KellyBundy: Updated with a version that replaces use of `del` with an equivalent slice assignment (and doesn't change behavior, because the initial indexing will still die for an empty `list` or an out-of-bounds index). A little ugly to handle the `-1` case (must use `index + 1 or None` for the end-of-slice index, so when `index` is `-1` it actually runs to the end of the `list`, instead of operating on a zero-length slice), but it works.

Comment: Yes, that special case is a pity, but not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few variants of popping items from a list without using `list` functions, only slicing & list comprehension

pop the last item using slicing & slicing assignment:

```
def pop_item(lst):
    lst[:] = lst[:-1]
```

pop a valued item (last one but can be a parameter) by rebuilding the list & slice assign

```
def pop_item(lst):
    lst[:] = [x for x in lst if x!=lst[-1]]
```

(that can pop other items in the list if they have the same value)

by speciftying item position/index in the list:

```
def pop_item(lst,item_position):
    lst[:] = [x for i,x in enumerate(lst) if i!=item_position]
```

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes! Thanks Jean!

Comment: But I _wear_ a cape!

Comment: It wont work in a loop, lets say I have another function called empty, which checks if the list is empty, def empty(lst): return lst == [], and i try do pop in a while loop until it is empty, it wont work.

Comment: if it's empty then comparing to `[]` works. Print the list before calling `empty`. Btw: `bool(lst)` works better to check for empty

Comment: so lets say if i had, while not empty(todo): print(remove_item(todo), it will print the first item in the list and then print an empty list, how would I fix that?

Answer (score -2):

```
li= [1,2,3,4]
def popl(li)
 li=li[1:]
popl(li)
print(li)
```

Comment: This does not do what you intend. Your `popl` makes a *local* copy of the list, makes a copy that excludes the *first* element, not the last, rebinds the local name, and then, when the function returns, all that work is thrown away and the caller's `list` remains unchanged.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.